# Java: Get Class<T> from generic T using GenericTypeResolver of spring within instance

Tags: java, spring, generics

This is my class:

```java
public class ReactiveJpaSpecificationExecutorImpl<T> implements ReactiveJpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {//...}
```

I need to get `Class<T>` inspecting on type.

I've tried it using `GenericTypeResolver` from `spring`:

```java
private Class<T> getEntityClazz() {
    return (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(
        this.getClass(),
        ReactiveJpaSpecificationExecutorImpl.class
    );
}
```

It returns `null`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `spec` parameter is unused.

Comment: Which class is your `getEntityClazz` method a member of?

Comment: I think a runnable example would help.

Comment: Where could I push a runnable code?

Comment: `getEntityClazz` is inside `ReactiveJpaSpecificationExecutorImpl`...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't fully explained what you are trying to do, but making some reasonable assumptions your code seems to work:

```java
import org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver;

class Foo<T> {
    public Class<T> getEntityClazz() {
        return (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(
                this.getClass(),
                Foo.class
        );
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo<String> {}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar b = new Bar();
        System.out.println(b.getEntityClazz());
    }
}
```

This prints `class java.lang.String`